# Java random name generator, selecting length of word

Tags: java

My Java program requires me to create a random name between 6-12 characters, the odd positions in the name have to be consonants and the even positions have to be vowels, so far I can't even get it to print random 12 letters.  The code below in the method brandName() should iterate and keep adding random letters to the string new_Name until it has 12 letters but whenever I run it it only prints one random letter to new_Name.  I've been trying ti figure it out for hours.... Code below

```
public class BrandName {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
int name_iterations = 1;
int name_counter = 0;
while (name_iterations <= 10) {
    name_counter++;
    name_iterations++;
    System.out.print("\n" + name_counter +") " + brandName());
    
    
    


    }
}
public static String brandName() {

 for (int iterations = 0; iterations <= 10; iterations ++); {
    String new_Name = "";
    
    int letter_Selector = 24;
    int randomChar = (int) (Math.random() * letter_Selector);
    
    
    String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmniprstuvwxz";
    String odd_Consonants = "bcdfghjklmnprstvwxz";
    String even_Vowels = "aeiou";

    for (int max_Name = 0; max_Name <= 12; max_Name++); {
    new_Name = new_Name + (alphabet.charAt(randomChar)); 
    return new_Name;
    } 
    
 }
    

 }
        
}
```

Comment: Java naming conventions use camelCase and do not use underscores (except for certain types of constants). Classes start with an upper case letter; methods and variables start with a lower case letter (ex. oddConsonants or newName).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the initialization of the string out of the loop:

```
for (int iterations = 0; iterations <= 10; iterations ++); {
    String new_Name = "";
```

to

```
String new_Name = "";
for (int iterations = 0; iterations <= 10; iterations ++); {
```

otherwise, each iteration you lose the previous random character from the previous iteration.

And then you need to wait for the loop to complete before returning:

```
for (int max_Name = 0; max_Name <= 12; max_Name++); {
    new_Name = new_Name + (alphabet.charAt(randomChar)); 
    // return new_Name; <-- remove this line
} 
return new_Name; // <-- and put it here
```

And now that I'm looking at it all together, I'm not sure what the `iterations` loop is doing, you probably just need to remove that part entirely

```
public static String brandName() {
  String new_Name = "";
  int letter_Selector = 24;

  String odd_Consonants = "bcdfghjklmnprstvwxz";
  String even_Vowels = "aeiou";
  int lengthSelector = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(5, 11 + 1);
  for (int max_Name = 0; max_Name <= lengthSelector; max_Name++) {
    if (max_Name % 2 == 0) {
        int randomChar = (int) (Math.random() * even_Vowels.length());
        new_Name = new_Name + (even_Vowels.charAt(randomChar));     
    } else {
        int randomChar = (int) (Math.random() * odd_Consonants.length());
        new_Name = new_Name + (odd_Consonants.charAt(randomChar));   
    }
    
  }
  return new_Name; 
}
```

Comment: I have tried all this but it still only prints one character.  Also you mean remove the iterations part from the brandName method or the main method?

Comment: I see you updated it.  It still only prints one letter though.  Doesn't make sense because new_Name is outside of that for loop.

Comment: forgot to move the randomChar inside the loop, try like this

Comment: then you'll want to do (roughly) `if (max_Name % 2 == 0) { even_Vowels.charAt(Math.random() * even_Vowels.length) } else { odd_Consonants.charAt(Math.random() * odd_Consonants.length) }`

Comment: Still only outputs one letter :/.

Comment: Thank you @dave that is how I planned to put the even and odds at the correct spot.  But I still need to first print random letters between 6-12 digits.

Comment: Weird... I went over my code and it was all the same of yours but then I copy and pasted yours and it worked.  Not sure what I was missing.  Ok!  that was the first issue.... So now I just need to figure out how to make it randomly pick between 6-12 characters and then implement what you showed above for the even and odds

Comment: for 6 -12, `length = 6 + (Math.random() * 6); for (max_Name <= length`

Comment: I just did import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom; and then did this int lengthSelector = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(5, 11 + 1); and passed it into the for statement as the max value so it randomly picks lengths between 6-12.

Comment: Dave, could you explain the even and odd code further?  Tried it out and it doesn't put vowels at all even number or consonants and all odds numbers?